# Issue moving database between servers (cannot find .frm file)

Tags: mysql

I used MAMP on my local machine to make a little site with a mysql database. I moved all the site files over the to server. Great.

The name of my database is roster and it has one table called users. I copied the 'roster' folder which contains the following files:

```
db.opt
users.frm
users.MYD
users.MYI
```

I put the 'roster' folder in the mysql directory. I run the following:

```
<?php
$db = mysql_connect("localhost","username","password") or die ('Fail message1');
mysql_select_db("roster") or die("Fail message2");
?>
```

No error. Awesome. But when I run the following:

```
$query = "SELECT last_name, first_name, u_name, skype_id, primary_location FROM users";

$result = mysql_query($query)or die('query error'.mysql_error());
```

Then I receive the following error:

```
query errorCan't find file: './roster/users.frm' (errno: 13)
```

The file is where it supposed to be, right? Did I move the database wrong? What gives? Any ideas?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about database managment. try dba.stackexchange.com

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up being a permissions issue. Changed group and user of each file to mysql and it worked!

Answer (score 3):

Copying files is not the proper method to transfer databases (it *may* work in many cases but there are so many things to take care of that it takes an experienced DB/Sysadmin to do so).

Instead, [dump your database and reimport](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/copying-databases.html) the dump on the target server.